# Efficient Way to Use/Access WAMP Server On Android Device (Tab/SmartPhone)

Tags: php, android, wifi

I am a desktop software and web developer (php/html). I am not so expert but know as far as to do what I need to do. 
But I am totally stranger when it comes to android.

O have a shop where I wanted to make the catalogue from Analog to modern/Digital.
So, I have purchased few tabs (Android Tabs) to show my products to my customer. 
Before/when I started I thought it is easy..

So, what I did?
I Make a web app/site/pages on my local (pc) server (wamp/easyphp) and connect to this webpage from my tabs using wifi.

But later I noticed that is too buggy. Wifi get down/disconnected very often. Speed is slow and when I move the tab just few feet far from the pc it's gets much slower (even don't work at all).

So, I see that is not acceptable as my customers will not use this buggy System.

And as I told earlier, I don't know anything about android development..

so, a better suggestion will be highly appreciated.

To connect to my pc via Wifi I am using Prolink N Nano Adapter with Access Point Mode.

Here is the dropbox link to download the WebPages/app to get idea what is looks like now..

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hx2i3apoydq6e2i/Tablet_Web_App.zip

Note: use index.php in V2 Folder

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser instead of the default one.

Install chrome browser from the play store -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome . It handles web pages very well, as far as web app user experience goes.

Don't expect it to get **much** better though. If you want fluid user experience you should build a native app for your catalogue.

Comment: sir, i already told i don't know nothing about android. 2nd, if native app then say for 10 tablet i have to store catelogues (Product Images)  10 times and it will be very time consuming to maintain all images on all 10 tabs as i have to delete images when products goes out and add images when new product comes in. Hope i am clear (sorry for my bad English)....

Comment: Actually no, you don't have to waste your time. Store the data (images, product list, etc) in your server, then provide a interface for querying this data from your device (php has easy support for json and http can serve images) and make your app load this data dynamically. Then you can only update your data in the server and let it "reflect" on all your devices. However, you do need to learn android and client/server architecture for this.

If you can't afford to learn about android right now, then try a different browser as i explained. And please, accept my awnser if it was helpfull.